# Atlassian Jira Dashboard - List Of Users' Most Recent Work Log Record

Tags: kanban, jira, work-in-progress

I'm new to Jira and cannot find any help, Google or otherwise, on simply making a Dashboard component which **lists all Users and their most recent Work Log entry**. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

I would take a look at the Jira [**tempo plugin**](http://www.tempoplugin.com/), it will solve all your time tracking and recording issues. We also combined it with [the worklog assistant](https://worklogassistant.com/), since not everyone likes to book hours, this will simplify it a lot.

List of recent work-items per project: https://tempoplugin.jira.com/wiki/display/TEMPO/List+View

Team time-sheets: https://tempoplugin.jira.com/wiki/display/TEMPO/Team+Timesheet

I would expect you can also add these list and views to your Jira Dashboards, although I never tried.

Comment: Was hoping for an unpaid gadget.  I may have to try one of the Tempo items.

Answer (score 2):

### You can use the Jira Activity Stream gadget

Yes, Jira has a built-in gadget to do this. It is the Activity Stream gadget:

[image]

You can add this gadget to your Dashboard and select all the projects that you want to track. I find this gadget very convenient to track all Jira and Confluence activities as a stream in the dashboard.

However, please note that I am using it for Scrum. You will have to try this for Kanban to see whether it meets your needs.

Comment: That was the second one I tried, but my "desire" is much more specific.  I literally in an ideal world would like a two or three column list.   Column 1, User name.  Column 2, just the MOST RECENT Work Log record summary.  Possibly column 3 of date/time, though that could be IN the column 2 summary.

Comment: Ultimately, out of the box, this seems like the closest to anything remotely like what I want, thanks  ;)

Answer (score 2):

Jira Activity stream has also a table view, which looks similar to what you requested:

[image]

To get that, Add Gadget to your Jira Dashboard and then use toolbar (seen on my screenshot) within the "Activity Stream" to switch to table view.

Comment: I know it seems obvious to you, as a user of the system, but can you please add some commentary in this answer which explains why this answers the OP's question, and perhaps also a description of how to run/find the screen(s) you are suggesting as answers? Without any further information it is not particularly helpful to anyone except the people that already know about it! Thanks.

Comment: Please add the information, including how to get to this screen, within your answer. That way it can help anyone who has the same problem. Additional information in comments can be deleted at any time...

Comment: I pulled that Gadget in, and it's certainly "in the right direction", thanks.  ;-)